# Grad double dot product vector simplification

Tags: vectors

The question is to show that:
$$
(\nabla \cdot \rho \mathbf {V V})\cdot \mathbf V = (\nabla \cdot \frac {\rho \mathbf V  V^2 }{2} ) 
$$

I have been stuck a while and would appreciate any help (solutions or hints). Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: what are those terms?

Comment: What conditions do you have on the terms included? I suspect, for instance, that you know something about $\rho\mathbf{V}$.

Answer (score 0):

In order to prove this, you have to assume that $\bf V$ is divergenceless (for example because it is the velocity field of a stationary flow).

It is then second relation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Divergence_2). In particular, it states that
$$\nabla \cdot (\psi {\bf A}) = \psi \nabla \cdot {\bf A}+ {\bf A}\cdot \nabla \psi.$$

Applying this to $$ {\bf A} = {\bf V}, \qquad \psi = \frac{\rho V^2}2,$$
we obtain
$$\nabla \cdot \left(\frac{\rho V^2}2 {\bf V} \right) =\frac{\rho V^2}2 \nabla \cdot {\bf V}+ {\bf V}\cdot \nabla \left(\frac{\rho V^2}2 \right) = {\bf V}\cdot \nabla \left(\frac{\rho V^2}2 \right)$$
provided that $\nabla \cdot {\bf V}=0$.